# Just installed Webform CiviCRM and cannot see the CiviCRM tab on webforms

Tags: webform-civicrm

I must be missing something very basic here.  Install went fine.  Supporting modules are all installed and enabled.  All the permissions I know to check have been checked.  However, the CiviCRM tab is not displayed on the webform edit page. The link suggesting I click on the tab is there but no tab.

[image]

I'm on Drupal 7.35 and Civi 4.6.2.

Comment: Hi Damon - can you list the module versions for Webform and Webform-CiviCRM? If you are certain they are compatible, have up run updb in case that is an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear Drupal's cache from your browser (not via Drush).

Comment: Cleared the cache from my browser and tried alternate browsers.  No luck.  However, your post reminded me to flush all the Drupal caches.  That did the trick!  I knew it had to be something simple.  Thanks!

Comment: Great! That's what I meant, but I've edited for clarity now. I wonder if you ran into [CRM-15632](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15632) when enabling/upgrading using the command line? That can prevent menu rebuild and cache clear.